# Dapper return specfic field from query

Tags: dapper

I am working on connecting to SQL database and setting variables in my C# application to match returned values from a Dapper Query.

I am able to return the correct row information (I used a datagridview to show that i get the correct row, and when i debug i see the right data) but how do I set a program variable to just one of the columns? here is some code showing my process

Connect & run stored procedure:

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString()))
        {
            DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
            param.Add("@UserID", txt_userid.Text.Trim());

            List<User> userinfo = conn.Query<User>("GetUserInfo", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<User>();

            Variables.UserID = txt_userid.Text.Trim();

            datagridview1.DataSource = userinfo; //this displays the right information, however I want to store the information as a public variable(like above)
            Variables.Userfull = userinfo; //when debugging this shows I have the right information but its all columns of user
```

User Class:

```
class User
{
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int AccessLevel { get; set; }
    public int FirstUse { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int LoginCounter { get; set; }
    public string LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string FirstLogin { get; set; }
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT

per answer, I have tried to switch the command to executescalar with this code:

```
var userinfo = conn.ExecuteScalar<User>("GetUserInfo", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

This allows me to set

```
Variables.UserID = userinfo.UserID;
```

without red-squiggle lines however during run-time i get an error on the execute scalar of "System.InvalidCastException: 'Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Name_Space.User'.'

I have checked the User Class to ensure the data type matches with the Database and i see no problems there, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want value from only one column of only one row, use `ExecuteScalar` which is similar to ADO.NET `ExecuteScalar`. It will return `object` with which you have to deal further.

```
string sql = "SELECT COL1 FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1";
//OR
//string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 COL1 FROM Table1";
//OR similar
object colValue = conn.ExecuteScalar(sql, ....);
```

If matching record not found, return value will be `null`.

Check Dapper documentation for other generic variants of method:

```
public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(this IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command);
```

---

If you want single column from multiple rows, the way you are doing this now is correct. Just modify your SQL query/Stored Procedure to return the same. Dapper will only map returned column. All other properties in your `User` will remain unassigned.

---

If you simply want to assign values to `Variables.UserID` instead of binding those using `DataSource`, then just do that like:

```
Variables.UserID = userinfo.UserID;
Variables.Userfull = userinfo.UserFullName;
//and so on....
```

So, complete code will be something like below:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MfgDataCollector"].ToString()))
{
    DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();
    param.Add("@UserID", txt_userid.Text.Trim());

    User userinfo = conn.Query<User>("GetUserInfo", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList<User>().First();

    Variables.UserID = userinfo.UserID;
    Variables.Userfull = userinfo.UserFullName;
}
```